# Why remoteCommand action grows exponentially?

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces RemoteCommand component vie jquery to call method from html table cells. However, when I update panel remoteCommand action calls method more than one. Growth curve is exponential. In the first action calls once, in second two times, in third four times and so on. What is the reason for this, and how can I solve this problem?

```
<p:panelGrid columns="1" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-12" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank" 
             style="border:0px none; background-color:transparent;">

    <p:panel  id="tablePanel" header="#{courseConstraintBean.selectedCourse == null ? 'SEÇİLİ DERSİN ' : 
                                        (courseConstraintBean.selectedCourse.courseNameWithClass)} 
              HAFTALIK DERS TABLOSU" 
              style="margin: 0 auto; min-width: 600px; margin-top: 2%;">

        <p:remoteCommand name="sendHourOrDay" actionListener="#{courseConstraintBean.changeLocationHourOrDayCondition(param.id)}" update="form:tablePanel"/>

        <p:remoteCommand name="sendLocation" actionListener="#{courseConstraintBean.changeLocationCondition( param.hour, param.day)}" update="form:tablePanel"/>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('td').click(function () {
                    sendLocation([{name: 'day', value: $(this).attr('data-day')}, {name: 'hour', value: $(this).attr('data-hour')}]);
                });
            });

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('th').click(function () {
                    sendHourOrDay([{name: 'id', value: $(this).attr('data-id')}]);
                });
            });

        </script>


        <p:messages id="classCourseChartMessage" showDetail="false" autoUpdate="false" closable="true" style=" margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%" />


        <p:panel style="margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%; margin-top: 1%; margin-bottom: 0%; min-width: 550px; background-color: #F6FFFF">

            <table width="100%" align="center" style="margin: 0px;">
                <div id="head_nav">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 16%; padding: 10px" data-id="times">DERSLER</th>
                        <th style="width: 12%;" data-id="d1">PZT</th>
                        <th style="width: 12%;" data-id="d2">SAL</th>
                        <th style="width: 12%;" data-id="d3">ÇARŞ</th>
                        <th style="width: 12%;" data-id="d4">PERŞ</th>
                        <th style="width: 12%;" data-id="d5">CUM</th>
                        <th style="width: 12%;" data-id="d6">CMT</th>
                        <th style="width: 12%;" data-id="d7">PZR</th>
                    </tr>
                </div>  

                <tr>
                    <th data-id="h1">1. Ders</th>  
                    <td style="background-color: #{courseConstraintBean.getLocationColorOfSelectedCourse(0, 0)}; font-size: 10px; color:#A8B4BB" data-hour="0" data-day="0">1</td>
                    <td style="background-color: #{courseConstraintBean.getLocationColorOfSelectedCourse(0, 1)}; font-size: 10px; color:#A8B4BB" data-hour="0" data-day="1">1</td>
                    <td style="background-color: #{courseConstraintBean.getLocationColorOfSelectedCourse(0, 2)}; font-size: 10px; color:#A8B4BB" data-hour="0" data-day="2">1</td>
                    <td style="background-color: #{courseConstraintBean.getLocationColorOfSelectedCourse(0, 3)}; font-size: 10px; color:#A8B4BB" data-hour="0" data-day="3">1</td>
                    <td style="background-color: #{courseConstraintBean.getLocationColorOfSelectedCourse(0, 4)}; font-size: 10px; color:#A8B4BB" data-hour="0" data-day="4">1</td>
                    <td style="background-color: #{courseConstraintBean.getLocationColorOfSelectedCourse(0, 5)}; font-size: 10px; color:#A8B4BB" data-hour="0" data-day="5">1</td>
                    <td style="background-color: #{courseConstraintBean.getLocationColorOfSelectedCourse(0, 6)}; font-size: 10px; color:#A8B4BB" data-hour="0" data-day="6">1</td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: Did you check if the jQuery 'click' handler is called multiple times? If so **that** is the problem. Might be that it is added multiple times?

Comment: May be, if so what should I do?

Comment: make sure it is not added multiple times?

Comment: How? I dont know so much about front end.

Comment: First check if it IS added multiple times. How? By adding console.log in the javascript, or use a browser developer tool with debugging options

Comment: The code was unneeded deep indented, it is not needed. The "{}" icon is a little bit tricky, but you can use that to fix it. I suspect, you have copy-pasted it from a complex code where this deep indentation was needed. I fixed the format. It is important, as you are asking a question, to make it so easily readable to the answerers as possible.

Comment: @peterh I think your intention is not to answer questions, you just want to score points by editing posts. Please don't be be nosy-parker. Learn coding and try to answer questions not edit!

Comment: Not exactly - my current intention is to help the site by advicing newbies. On the long-term, my intention is to get answers to my questions and give wonderful answers to others. Similarly to you. I gave you a lot of help already - I gave you advices, infos how things are going here, I *fixed your questions*, while I remained in a relatively cooperative context, despite it is not what I got back from you. Btw, maybe you could check my top tags and top posts to see about my skills and main focus of interest, if you are curious. These infos are available on my profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `click` event is binding multiple times. this could be because you are updating very own `p:panel` which contains the script.(this should not be a problem because you are using `$(document).ready(...)`).
But just to solve the multiple bindings of an event you could use JQuery's `unbind()`.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $('td').unbind('click');
      $('td').click(function () {
         ...
      });
 });
</script>
```

But keep in mind that binding/unbinding the event directly using TAG name like `$('TD'), $('TR')...` will affect other tags generated by JSF/Primefaces as well.

So I'd suggest you to bind the events through CSS class selector, for example:

```
<td class="clickable-cell">...</td>
<td class="clickable-cell">...</td>
<td class="clickable-cell">...</td>
<td class="clickable-cell">...</td>

<script>
$('.clickable-cell').click(...);
</script>
```